# Serial Port Programming using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, msdn

I have a Host machine and a target machine Connected using the `USB` to serial and Serial to `USB`. *[All drivers are installed and connection established between host and target]*

**Current Working**:

Host machine program  : Writes data and tries to identify data was not read by target machine or not.
Target machine program: Just read the data on the serial port regularly. No feedback

I am writing a Data from Host machine to SerialPort's ( Outbuffer ) using C# function Host's `SerialPort.WriteLine()`. This will be read by a program in target machine which reads data using Target's `SerialPort.ReadLine()`.

**Requirement:**

To write and receive data from Host to Target. 
Program running on Host machine has to ensure that Target reads data from its buffer without getting feedback from target machine. Is it possible ?

**Conditions:**

Acknowledgement from the target machine for data received is not allowed.

Comment: How should that work? How should the sender know that the receiver has successfully received the data when you don't allow an acknowledgement? You can add forward error checking to improve the possibility that the receiver will be able to successful parse the data and even fix a number of lost bytes, but there's no way that you can guarantee that the receiver will get the data if you don't allow a reverse channel to request resending any lost data.

Comment: Thanks For your inputs.. But the requirement is there are chances that target machine may be disconnect due to some problems. I wanted to ensure the differences between " Cable Disconnected " and "Target machine " Not running..

Comment: Without Acknowledgement this should be possible Conceptually [But not sure about possibilities using C#].

Comment: I have placed a data at some common location[Buffer used for transfer b/w Host and Target]. When someone(target) reads it and deletes it, buffer would be empty. If buffer is not empty, it means data was not read by Target. If buffer is empty , it means data was read by target. Is it feasible ?

Comment: No, because the serial port can send data regardless of whether somebody is actually reading it. However, you could check for the serial port status lines and use these as kind of acknowledgement. If the CTS bit is not set, the sender can assume nobody is listening to the data. If you enable hardware handshaking, no data will be physically sent until CTS goes high.

Comment: Thanks alot  :) I think SerialPort.CDHolding will be more apt to mycase ..

Comment: Yes, you've got the two lines, but they should be equivalent in this case (modern computers are fast enough such that CTS will never go low during reception as they can read the data as fast as they're sent)